# C++ where I can find the implementation files of the standard library for the gcc compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu, standard-library

I am looking for the implementation files of the c++ standard library (the .cpp files) for the gcc compiler. For instance, where I can find the implementation of the method `basic_istream& read( char_type* s, std::streamsize count )` of the `istream` class.

Here you  find the ouput of `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)
```

Comment: It depends entirely upon the compiler.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question after the edits... There's a single (or very few) correct answer, and knowing the right keywords to search for this is not so trivial, that it'd be wrong to ask here.

Comment: @Thomas Could you add output of `gcc -v` to the question, to make it clear which *gcc* you are using.

Comment: In the GCC source code, see https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=summary - specifically in `libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc` which is a header so you will have it installed as part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely : I don't need the header file. Headers are installed an available on the machine.  I really need the .cpp file where some functions are defined.

Comment: The function you asked about is defined inline in the header. If you're after some other functions then you should have said so, but you will still find them in the GCC source code, obviously.

Comment: I find the implementation file here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src. I found istream.cc. But strangely I didn't find the `read` function. I checked on my header file and that function is not declared inline.

Comment: Put the word in Searchlight and double click on the result.

Comment: @Thomas: look in the file that JonathanWakely directed you to.

Answer (score 0):

The gcc compiler does not implement the standard library.  It is designed to be used in conjunction with a separate project that implements the standard library.  This applies to both the C Standard Library, and the C++ Standard Library.

GNU/Linux systems commonly use [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) as the C Standard Library, and [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) as the C++ Standard Library.  Other choices are possible however.